# How to get output like this in Javascript/ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

Let's say you have an array like this:

//Input
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

How to write the function which will get us the output of

//Output

```
 Array1 = [1]
 Array2 = [1,2]
 Array3 = [1,2,3]
 Array4 = [1,2,3,4]
 Array5 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And

//Output
1. `[1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4...]`

// tried this

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    arr = new Array(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you think of how you’d print a triangle? `*` `**` `***` `****`?

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried? What exactly are you stuck on? This isn't a code-writing service. We would much prefer to act as your mentors rather than your employees.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). –

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions like [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to easily create the first function, and use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to flatten a 2D array.

```js
function prefixes(array) {
  return array.map((_, index) => array.slice(0, index + 1));
}

function flatten(array) {
  return [].concat(...array);
}

const output = prefixes([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
console.log(output);
console.log(flatten(output));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by slicing the wanted part with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    result = array.reduce((r, _, i, a) => [...r, ...a.slice(0, i + 1)], []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and for loop

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var arrys = [];
//lopping over the array, and creating the new array and putting values
// equal to number of index
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  var tempArray = [];
  for (var m = 0; m <= index; m++) {
    tempArray.push(arr[m])
  }
  arrys.push(tempArray)
})
console.log(arrys)
// flat the previously created array
var flatten = [];
arrys.forEach(function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(item2) {
    flatten.push(item2)
  })
})
console.log(flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using two nested for loops like this,

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
function foo(arr) {
    let rarr = [];//result array
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let a = [];//array[i]
        for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            a.push(arr[j]);
        }
        rarr.push(a);
    }
    return rarr;
}
console.log(foo(arr));
```